# Node.JS - Promise to Async/Await example

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I currently have a project which makes use of native Promises. I am looking to migrate these Promises over to Async/Await. I am having troubles migrating them over; I am trying to follow [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) article. Below is the current code with the Promises which need changing to Async/Await.

**routes.js**

```
// Importing user information
import user from '../server-controllers/user';

// User Information Route
router.get('/about', (req, res) => {
  user.profile().then((data) => {
    return res.render('user', {
      title: data,
    });
  }).catch((e) => {
    res.status(500, {
      error: e,
    });
  });
});
```

**user.js**

```
/*
This file contains any server side modules needed.
*/

module.exports = {
// Returns information about a user
  profile: () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const user = "John Doe";
      resolve(user);
    });
  },
};
```

If there is any help in what I would need to do to convert these that would be helpful. I don't know if the code needs changing on either the `routes` or `user` file (or both).

The error which I am getting in my terminal is `[object Error] { ... }`

Comment: Here's a whole app with async / await: https://github.com/bryanmacfarlane/sanenode

Comment: Just replace every `then` call by `await`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key thing to remember about `async` and `await` is that an `async` function is really just a function that returns a `Promise`, and lets you use `await` to resolve `Promise`s. So when a `Promise` rejects, if it is `await`ed then you will get an error thrown in the context of wherever the `await` is.

So technically, if you want to use `async`/`await` syntax, you don't *need* to change `user.js`. You could just change `routes.js` to:

```javascript
// Importing user information
import user from '../server-controllers/user'

// User Information Route
router.get('/about', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const data = await user.profile()
    return res.render('user', {
      title: data
    })
  } catch (error) {
    // Runs if user.profile() rejects
    return res.status(500, {error})
  }
})
```

But `user.js` *is* made more succinct when you use an `async` function:

```javascript
module.exports = {
  // Returns information about a user
  // This returns a Promise that resolves to 'John Doe'
  profile: async () => 'John Doe'
}
```